# how to select a radio button from excel sheet data with selenium webdriver + Data driven concept

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, jxl

I was tried to select a radio button by using excel sheet data with selenium webdriver data. the following code is working for some kind of radio button, but it doesn't support for some radio buttons. kindly help me. which kind code is much better to select radio button.

```
List<WebElement> as=driver.findElements(By.name("Contacts[salary_range]"));
        if(annual.equals(as.get(0).getAttribute("value")))
        {
            as.get(0).click();
        }
        else if(annual.equals(as.get(1).getAttribute("value")))
        {
            as.get(1).click();
        }
        else if(annual.equals(as.get(2).getAttribute("value")))
        {
            as.get(2).click();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by :  but it doesn't support for some radio buttons.??

Comment: What do you mean by some radio button? I know only one radio button!

Comment: in my applications there are n number of radio buttons, thats why i told like some radio buttons.  @VivekSingh

Comment: better tell me a simple code to access the radio button with datadriven + selenium webdriver

Comment: in my applications there are n number of radio buttons, thats why i told like some radio buttons. @HelpingHands